# Java input, scanner and if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I have an assignment like this:

Write a complete program called ExamResult with the behavior shown below. 
Read user input for a student’s internal test score and final exam score.

An internal test score below 20 will cause the student to be failed; 
final examscore below 40 will also cause the student to be failed.

Otherwise the student has passed.

Semester Examination Results!

What is your internal test score? 21

What is your final exam score? 69

You have passed!

So far I've figured out that using an if statement with a scanner for input would be appropriate. 
For now this is my code (I do have class, import java util and main methode above. I choose not to include it here)

```
  System.out.println("Semester Examination Results!");

  System.out.println("What is your internal test score?");

  //input
  //calculate input
  //does input pass the if test?
  //output passed/failed

  int score1 = scanner.nextLine();
  int score2 = scanner.nextLine();

  if (int score1 < 20; || score2 < 40;)
  {
     System.out.println("You have failed");
  }
  else
  {
     System.out.println("You have passed");
  }
```

What I'm unsure about is how to use input for calculation?

Comment: `if (int score1 < 20; || score2 < 40;)` ain't gonna end well. Remove the `;`s, and the `int`.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading a java tutorial for beginners and then posting questions here on Stack Overflow. It is OK to ask "well researched" basic questions :)

Comment: I'm reading my book over and over, and try to research, it's just that it's so new, so I'm easily confrused :P

Comment: @TinaDitte - I think you should divide the problem into smaller pieces and attack them one after another. I would start with searching "how to read an Integer using Scanner` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scanner.nextInt() instead of nextLine(). You also do not need the semi-colons inside the if statement.

> Edit1

You do not need to reinitialize score1 and 2 in the if statement. It ahould look like this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//init and read in values here
if(score1 < 20 || score2 < 40){
   //do stuff
}
else{
    //do other stuff
}
```

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
      int score2 = scanner.nextInt();

It can't find the symbol for scanner. What do I do?

Comment: @TinaDitte - You have not declared / initialized a `Scanner`. Add `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); ` before `int score1`

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove `;` from the conditions as these are not any statements. Remove `int` also.

  ```
  if (int score1 < 20; || score2 < 40;)
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  if (score1 < 20 || score2 < 40)
  ```
- Also, use `nextInt()` or `Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine())` for taking integer input.